How to include a modulus operation in CasADi function
I can't find a modulus function in CasADi.  I want to build a function with something like this:
from casadi import MX

angle = MX.sym('angle')

wrapped_angle = ((angle + 180) % 360) - 180

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'MX' and 'int'

There doesn't appear to be a mod or divmod function as far as I can see.
Maybe it's not implemented for a reason, but if so I would like to know that.

is this what you're looking for ? https://web.casadi.org/python-api/ , search for fmod

Right, thanks.  Searching for "mod" and "modulus" and not "remainder" was where I went wrong.

Casadi fmod has some unconventional behaviour: np.mod(-90.0, 360.0), -90 % 360, cas.fmod(-90.0, 360.0) -> (270.0, 270, -90.0) (see this C++ reference)

Ah, so 'fmod' stands for "floating point remainder" which is not the same as mod apparently.  Numpy also has an fmod function.  So I guess there is no equivalent to np.mod?

This seems to be the equivalent of the Python mod operator (and numpy.mod) but it involves conditional code and/or a divide which is less than desirable:
import numpy as np
import casadi as cas

def cas_mod(a, b):
    if (a < 0.0) != (b < 0.0):
        a += (cas.floor(-a / b) + 1) * b
    return cas.fmod(a, b)

# Test
angles = np.linspace(-450, 450, 11)
b = 360
print(np.stack([
    angles,
    np.mod(angles, b),
    [a % b for a in angles],
    np.array([cas_mod(a, b) for a in angles]).reshape(-1)
]))

Output:
[[-450. -360. -270. -180.  -90.    0.   90.  180.  270.  360.  450.]
 [ 270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.]
 [ 270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.]
 [ 270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.]]


Thinking about it a bit more, in my specific application (i.e. angles) I should avoid any kind of mod and use arctan2(sin(theta), cos(theta)) (or if possible, avoid angles completely and work with (x,y) vectors instead).
import casadi as cas

def wrapped_angle_radians(theta):
    return cas.arctan2(cas.sin(theta), cas.cos(theta))

def wrapped_angle_360(angle):
    theta = angle * cas.pi / 180.0
    angle = wrapped_angle_radians(theta) * 180.0 / cas.pi
    return cas.fmod(angle + 360.0, 360)

# Test
angles = np.linspace(-450, 450, 11)
print(np.stack([
    angles,
    np.mod(angles, 360),
    np.array([wrapped_angle_360(a) for a in angles]).reshape(-1)
]))

Output:
[[-450. -360. -270. -180.  -90.    0.   90.  180.  270.  360.  450.]
 [ 270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.]
 [ 270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.  180.  270.    0.   90.]]

